# Find largest path featuring pattern in Neo4j with Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have the following node types, and a pattern to find:

### Node Labels

Questions
Outcomes

### Relationship

Answers (with a 'title' field)

I want to "find all questions that are connected to each other by "no" answers and all have a "yes" answer to the same outcome" - i suspect there are hundreds of these groups in my database, some are just two nodes in size, some are up to 5 or 6 nodes. None bigger than six.

So I can match all answers joined by nos in a 2-group:

(outcome)<-[yes]-(question)->[no]->(question)->[yes]->(outcome)

But i can't figure out how to apply that to 3 or 4-groups. I thought i could perhaps do a straight:

(question)<-[no][0..*]-(question) - and find all the questions joined by nos, then in a WHERE clause add something like WHERE *all matched questions* point to -> outcome - but i have no idea how to express that in cypher

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RE-RE-EDITED]

This might work for you.

```
MATCH p=(oc:Outcome)<-[:Answer {title: 'yes'}]-(q1:Question)-[:Answer* {title: 'no'}]->(q2:Question)-[:Answer {title: 'yes'}]->(oc)
WHERE
  NOT (
    (oc)<-[:Answer {title: 'yes'}]-(:Question)-[:Answer {title: 'no'}]->(q1) OR
    (q2)-[:Answer {title: 'no'}]->(:Question)-[:Answer {title: 'yes'}]->(oc)
  ) AND
  ALL(q IN NODES(p)[1..-1] WHERE (q)-[:Answer {title: 'yes'}]->(oc))
RETURN oc, NODES(p)[1..-1] AS questions;
```

The `NOT (...)` term in the `WHERE` clause is there to make sure we only use the *longest* valid sequences of `Questions`.

Each result row contains a shared outcome and an ordered collection of Question nodes.

This query can take a long time to finish, as it does not specify an upper bound for the variable length pattern. You may want to specify an appropriate upper bound if this is a problem (e.g., `Answer*..5`).

Comment: Marked as answer because this helped me out a lot, thanks! The problem that I have is that the "intermediary" questions (rels:Answer*) also need to have a 'yes' relationship to the outcome (oc) - at the moment it looks like it's only enforcing that yes relationship at either end

Comment: I have updated my answer, and it should now ensure that all the other relationships have 'no' titles (which is what I believe you stated you wanted in your question).

Comment: I have re-edited my answer, now that I think I understand what you were really asking for.

Comment: We're just puzzling over how to find only the 'longest path containing a particular question' - i thought i'd post it here in case we end up finding nothing

This query matches a '4-question-group' e.g. [Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4] but you also then get [Q1,Q2], [Q2,Q3], [Q3,Q4] in the results (for example) - it would be nice to be able to say "only show the longest group with a particular question id in". I don't think it's possible for questions to be in multiple groups.

Returning like: RETURN oc, extract(n IN questions| n.id) AS extracted, size(questions) AS noOfQuestions ORDER BY noOfQuestions DESC

Comment: Your colleagues could also up-vote (if they had enough points) :-). Anyway, I have re-re-edited my answer. I have not tested it, but it should give you only the longest valid question chains.